# Finely Control the output of GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, x86

For some reasons, I want to be able to fine tune the final executables generated for my C++ program - down to individual instructions.  As I recall, GCC should generate some text assembler file as intermediate output before feeding it to the assembler for generating the final binary object file.

Is it possible for me to extract this assembler source, edit it programatically and feed this modified version to the final assembler for generating my custom object file?  I am targeting the Windows platform.

Does MSVC++ support similar feature?

And if you wonder why, part of the reason is to prevent reverse engineering by including our custom polymorphic code generation logic.  Another reason, is to create hidden identification within each copy distributed to customers in order to deter anyone cracking our protection and distributing his cracked version.

Comment: Why don't you just write your code in assembly?!

Comment: You could always dissassemble your code (using a dissassembler like IDA or Win32DAsm) and reassemble it, but I really don't see the point of doing that. Care to elaborate more on your purpose? Maybe there are other, less Sisyphian, methods of doing what you want...

Comment: We want to make our code polymorphic to defeat reverse engineering.

Comment: The chances of your code being valuable are approximately zero. I'm not being insulting, I mean that ALL code has more or less zero monetary worth. And I'm not clear you understand what "polymorphic" means.

Comment: Couldn't someone reverse engineer your code polymorphism?

Comment: @Neil: This is a valid use of the term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code.

Comment: Another reason is the polymorphic code serves as a hidden identification of who own whict copy.  This can at least deter someone cracking our protection and distribute his copy.

Comment: Copy protection is also a waste of time. You sound like some throw-back to  the 1980s.

Comment: @Oli Thanks, I'd never come across that before. And I would NEVER buy business software that used it.

Comment: So, asking about copy protection scheme here would cause someone voted down?  I'm not sure if the intermediate assembler file is modifiable and don't have enough assembly programming skill (yet) to try it myself.

Comment: @JavaMan I haven't voted you down. But what you are suggesting doing is a waste of time and effort. Concentrate on adding value to your product, not finding ways of stopping people using it.

Comment: Sorry, one of my comments way back should have read "more or less zero monetary worth outside of the company that owns the code". Not sure what happened there.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth How would you know if any business software you bought used polymorphic code? Have you ever compared the .exe files a vendor gives you with those a different customer of theirs got? What would the drawback to your business be if they differed?

Comment: @Baffe Well, I'm a pretty techie sort of guy, so I suspect that one way or another I would find out if they used it. But then again, I don't see the need to buy horizontal market applications (or most vertical ones). The only paid-for software I have on my machine is a few old games, the OS itself, and Help & Manual - because there is simply nothing better for writing documentation. But then again, I get all my computer hardware stuff from PoundLand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the `-S` flag:

```
g++ -S file.c -o output.s
```

Then make your *fine tuning* on `output.s` and compile the final executable with:

```
g++ output.s -o application
```

Comment: I don't know if MSVC++ supports this kind of thing, but there's a GCC port to Windows called **MinGW**, which you could use to accomplish this. See: http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. On Linux, try this:

```
$ cat hello.cc
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}

$ g++ -S hello.cc && sed -i 's/Hello, world/Goodbye, world/' hello.s && g++ -o goodbye hello.s && ./goodbye
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gcc can produce assembler intermediate output at the compilation phase, via `gcc -S`. You can generate different assembler outputs with the various optimisation levels `-On` where `n=0,1,2,3`. If you do this, you'll notice `-O3` in particular produces things that aren't, in your head, mapped directly to C code because gcc has implemented the code optimally.

MSVC can do the same thing via `cl.exe /Fafilename.asm`. The msdn documentation for this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Note that if you want comparable-ish syntax you probably want `gcc -masm=intel -S` on the gcc end. Note also that there will be some differences between Microsoft's Macro assembler output and GNU AS's output. I'm not familiar with MASM but there are subtle differences between all assemblers (as well as the obvious AT&T vs Intel syntax).